# making button open link

Tags: swift, apple-watch

I am new to swift but know the basics. I have tried my hand using Webkit but since I'm making a watch app it don't work. is there a way to make something that opens a link when a button is pressed. please a simple solution.

Comment: What does "opens a link" even mean? The user taps a button and then what's supposed to happen?

Answer (score 2):

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let urlString: String?
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if let safeString = urlString {
            if let url = URL(string: safeString) {
                let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                uiView.load(request)
            }
        }
    } 
}

struct ContentView: View{
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(destination: LinkView()) {
                Text("Open Link")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LinkView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebView(urlString: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71452673/making-button-open-link")
    }
}
```

[image]